# Using Openjfx 11 classes in an OSGi application

Tags: maven, osgi, eclipse-rcp, openjfx, javafx-11

Does anyone know if there is a way to use JavaFX modules in eclipse workspace? I have an OSGi-maven multi-modular application.

Up until now, I have tried a couple of things.

1. To download JavaFX SDK and to add jars in eclipse as a user-defined library.
2. To bundle JavaFX jars and to use them as regular OSGi bundles after that (added as dependency and after that in target-platform).

Both of these things work. But, in the first case, every developer would have to manually add those jars as a library on the classpath. And in the second for every platform, we would have to have a different bundle for each module.

If I do neither of those things I have compile errors that JavaFX classes cannot be found (as expected).

Is there some third way to do this? By using some OSGi functionality or something like that? 
I haven't found any way to add a module in MANIFEST.MF. Is that even possible?

I have added JavaFX modules as VM arguments in the OSGi framework launcher, and everything works fine. But I have to do one of those things mentioned before so that I don't have compile errors.
VM arguments: `--module-path /path/to/javafx/sdk/11/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.graphics,javafx.base`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to convert an E4/OSGI/GEF/JavaFx project that uses JRE 8 to JRE 11 and OpenJFX 11, and found a way to do so.

In my case, I use SWT and `javafx.embed.swt.FxCanvas`. Including the user defined JavaFX library in the modulepath didn't work, generating class not found errors during compile-time; but including the library in classpath worked.

I also couldn't run the application using `--module-path` arguments; it gave `NoClassDefFoundError` exception for `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas`

My solution uses E(fx)clipse, which could also be the third option for you. After including the javafx libraries in the classpath, and including `org.eclipse.fx.osgi` in the project configuration, I used the following VM parameters to load JavaFX classes using E(fx)clipse.

`-Dosgi.framework.extensions=org.eclipse.fx.osgi -Defxclipse.java-modules.dir=[openjfx-lib-directory]`

You can also add `-Defxclipse.osgi.hook.debug=true"` to see debug messages from E(fx)clipse while loading the classes.